# jQuery to PHP: no input... kinda

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, http

I'm using jQuery to post HTTP requests to my PHP page (Apache/Linux, if that matters). I carefully validate on the client so that empty requests are not sent. However on occasions, I'd get an empty request like this:
 - $_POST collection empty ($_GET collection also empty);
 - Content-Length is nonzero (a number below 100, consistent with a valid POST from my script)
 - Content-Type properly application/x-www-form-urlencoded
 - reading from php://input yields an empty string

It's as if $_POST is somehow eaten on the way. I checked the code very carefully - I don't do anything to the contents of $_POST.

CLARIFICATION: I do catch this condition on the server; it's not like my code dies horribly. But I have a very strong feeling that it's not genuine lack of user input, but some kind of data corruption en route. Why else would there be a nonzero Content-Length?

If the client-side validation failed, I'd get a $_POST with empty fields. The way things are, I'm getting no fields at all. Utterly perplexed.

Any ideas, please?

UPDATE: the client-side request submittal code goes like this:

```
var r = trim((re = document.getElementById("tread")).value),
    m = trim((me = document.getElementById("tmean")).value);
if(r == "" && m == "")
    alert("Please provide.");
else
{
    $.post(URLPrefix + "tsearch.php", {R : r, M : m, Src:"bytext"}, DoneSearch, "html");
}
```

There's also another request to the same server-side script, which goes:

```
$.post(URLPrefix + "tsearch.php", {K0 : KCode(0),
    K1 : KCode(1), K2 : KCode(2), K3 : KCode(3),
    P : document.getElementById("pos").checked ? 1 : 0,
    Src:"bykanji"}, DoneSearch, "html");
```

I don't see how this code, where all fields are unconditional, can provide an empty POST collection.

Answer (score 0):

If you're validating on the client side using jQuery/Javascript, clients with scripting turned off will not hit you validation code. If you want to test for that, have an additional hidden field and set it to a value using JS in your form.

e.g. In your form, have

```
<input  type="hidden" value="False, JS is off" name="my-hidden-field" />
```

and int your javascript

```
$('#my-hidden-field').val('True, JS is on');
```

You can use this to see if the empty posts are a result of your validation code failing to run on the client side of things.

Comment: jQuery post() is invoked from the script to begin with. There's no form/action/method combo as a backup. So if scripting is off on the client, nothing will ever work. Also, I can see, in my logs, a series of requests from very obviously the same user - same IP, within minutes of one another, and all of them except one look proper (with $_POST variables in them).

Answer (score 0):

I would honestly suggest doing both client-side and server-side validation.  Checking for empty/null inputs in the $_POST[] array using PHP is trivial.  **Presumably** your JavaScript should catch the empty inputs and not allow the request but just in case someone by-passes your JS you should always double check on the server.  Something as simple as:

```
if(empty($_POST['val']))
 // throw error
```

Would work just fine, you can either halt all processing from that point or handle it any way you like.  If data validation is important I really think it should be done on the server, JavaScript (or anything that is strictly client-side) is just too easy to tinker with.